# Configuring Sun 2270 to use RAID-5?

Tags: raid, solaris, software-raid

We're investigating using some low-end Suns ([2270](http://www.sun.com/servers/index.xml)).  These machines have 4 drive bays so it seems that we could run the systems in RAID-5 with ZFS.

First, I want to know if this can be done.  This would software RAID so my next question is: should we?

Will we get better performance over simply mirroring two drives onto the other two the drives?

Comment: What version of Solaris are you planning on running?  The assumption here is 10 U8 as it's the newest but it doesn't hurt to explicitly state this in your question.  ZFS as a root file system wasn't supported until 10 U6.

Comment: I'll be running the latest version.  We have U7 with ZFS on our current boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use all the four drives as RaidZ as your server won't be bootable. Booting Solaris is supported only on a single disk or a mirrored one.

Depending on your requirements, you might either use one disk to boot and configure the remaining three as RaidZ or create two simple mirrors, one system and one data/application.

Comment: jlliagre is correct RaidZ is not supported for a root pool so your options will be limited with a system with only 4 drives.  Two mirror pools aren't going to give you any performance improvements over single drives but I wouldn't run a production system without mirrored OS drives.

Answer (score 1):

ZFS doesn't have the write hole; it uses check-summing and variable raid stripe sizes to eliminate it.

You will need a single drive (or mirror) for your root partition, but you can use RAIDZ on zfs.

Answer (score -2):

RAID 5, especially software RAID 5 in my opinion is simply not reliable, as the parity calculations are not atomic (google for RAID 5 write hole). My own opinion with 4 drives in the machines would be to use RAID 1+0 by default. This may depend on what these machines are being used for though, RAID 1+0 is not suitable for everything.

In terms of performance, RAID 5 has poorer write performance for applications with small writes (e.g. mail server, database server) but much better write performance for large writes (e.g. samba share, nfs share.)

In a 4 disk setup, in general, you would expect RAID 5 would out perform RAID 10 for reads. RAID 5 is reading from 3 disks (the fourth is the parity) and RAID 10 is reading from two "disks" (i.e. two mirrors.). Some hardware arrays optimize RAID 10 for reading (as there is two copies of the data) and reading can potentially be much faster on RAID 10 depending on your controller and disk setup.

This is the kicker though... RAID 1+0 gives you much better redundancy. Because 1+0 means mirror, then stripe, you can lose a disk from each mirror (i.e. in a 4 disk setup you can potentially lose 2 disks if they are the "right" two) and still have a fully functioning array.

Because of the write hole in RAID 5, I wouldn't consider it again in a situation unless I had a battery backed hardware controller and even then, I think my preference would be strongly leaning towards RAID 1+0 unless I really needed the space.

+1 for ZFS though, that filesystem kicks ass.

Comment: While I personally think the write hole issue in RAID5/6 is not as big of an issue as people like to make it sound like in reality.  It is a real problem in theory.  But ZFS is a transactional, copy on write, filesystem and RAIDZ does not suffer from the write hole issue.  http://blogs.sun.com/bonwick/entry/raid_z